# Parallelizing a code with dependency

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, openmp, hpc

I have a code looks like:

Array `a` contains information about group it's elements belong to. i.e. element `i` belongs to group `a[i]`. Each group can contains two elements. I want to store this information in b whose length is `2*number` of groups. So, value at `b[j]` and `b[j+1]` would give me the elements that belong to group `j/2` (integer division) and `j` are even.

```
void assign(int *a, int *b){
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        int group = a[i];
        int posit=2*group;
        if(b[2*i]!=0){
            posit++;
        }
        b[posit] = i;
    }
}

N as is clear length of a.
```

By default value in b[] is zero and indicates absence of elements.

There is clear data dependency, and it does not look that easy to parallelize this. I am looking for further suggestions, if there is an smart way that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could try to simply use a parallel sort algorithm, on an array containing pairs `{i, a[i]}`. Maybe there is a quicker generic method that I don't see at the moment...

In CUDA specifically, however, you can take advantage from the fact that when you have 2 conflicting threads writing a 32-bit word to the same memory location -- one is guaranteed to succeed (you don't know which one though). Formally, it acts as an [Arbitrary CRCW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine) machine.

Thus, you can solve your problem in 2 kernel calls:

```
__global__ void assign1(int* a, int* b, int elementCount) {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx<elementCount) {
        int group = a[idx];
        b[2*group] = idx;
    }
}

__global__ void assign2(int* a, int* b, int elementCount) {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx<elementCount) {
        int group = a[idx];
        if (b[2*group] != idx)
            b[2*group+1] = idx;
    }
}

__host__ void assign(int* dev_a, int* dev_b, int elementCount) {
    int gridSize = elementCount/512+1;
    int blockSize = 512;
    assign1<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b, elementCount);
    assign2<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b, elementCount);
}
```

In `assign1` up to 2 threads write to the same memory location `b[2*group]`. One of these threads is guaranteed to succeed. In `assign2` the thread that failed the write, repeats the process with `b[2*group+1]`.

This approach could be repeated if there were up to 3 or 4 elements in the group, but as the number gets higher, it can quickly stop being feasible.